# Ito integral approximation by Euler?

Tags: stochastic-processes

I was wondering how to find the solution of the following stochastic integral:

$$dY_{t}=a(W_{t},Y_{t})dW_{t}+b(W_{t},Y_{t})dZ_{t}$$
or in integral notation
$$Y_{t}=Y_{0}+\int_{0}^{t}a(W_{s},Y_{s})dW_{s}+\int_{0}^{t}b(W_{s},Y_{s})dZ_{s}$$

where $W_{t}$ and $Z_{t}$ are two independent Wiener processes.
Can I approximate this with the Euler scheme? If so, how do I know it will actually converge. If not, is there any way to find it?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Do you know the functions $\alpha$ and $\beta$? Can you write the process in vector form on $(Y_t,W_t)$?

Comment: $a$ will be something like $Y_{t}*W_{t}$ and $b=1-a$. So you cannot vectorize it.

Comment: Does the work of [Platen](http://www.uts.edu.au/staff/eckhard.platen) say something about your case? $\int Y_t W_t dW_t$ looks difficult ...

Comment: I will check it out. But Euler is a no go?

Comment: seems legit: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maruyama_method

Answer (score 2):

You can write it as
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}dY_t\\ dX_t\end{array} \right) =
\left(\begin{array}{cc}\alpha(X_t, Y_t)& \beta(X_t,Y_t)\\ 1 & 0\end{array} \right)\cdot \left(\begin{array}{c}dW_t\\ dZ_t\end{array} \right)
$$
and check Platen's conditions (Lipschitz?) as Richard pointed out on the matrix perhaps?

If it is 
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}dY_t\\ dX_t\end{array} \right) =
\left(\begin{array}{cc}X_t Y_t& 1-X_t Y_t\\ 1 & 0\end{array} \right)\cdot \left(\begin{array}{c}dW_t\\ dZ_t\end{array} \right)
$$
I think that it should be fine.